# I want to add subject , attachment,and email address with navigateToURL functionality

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I want to   add subject , attachment,email address  with **navigateToURL** functionality.How to achieve it in Adobe air and Flex?

Answer (score 2):

refer a following code.

```
var format:String = "mailto:address@address.com?subject=mySubject&body=myMessage";

navigateToURL(new URLRequest(format));
```

Comment: That is what I would have said too.  I assume it is not possible to add an attachment to an email via a URL.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, NavigateToURL DOES NOT support attachments.

I think you should look at [STMPMailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27) to accomplish this.